# The meaning of Second order condition of Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the second derivative measures how much the derivative is changing. For  a function (,) : If  ″()<0, then the derivative is getting smaller (so the graph of   is concave down); if  ″()>0, then the derivative is growing, making the graph of   concave up.
But what does this mean:  >0
I want to a answer to explain the meaning of the two variables partial derivatives.
You can explain it in the method of mathematical economics.